# EInvalidCast exception is raised when assign a procedure of object, via TRttiProperty.SetValue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

I'm trying assign a property which is of type `procedure of object` via rtti using the `TRttiProperty.SetValue` procedure, but this exception is raised when i try the made the assignment `EInvalidCast: Invalid class typecast`

This sample application shows the issue

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
 Rtti,
 SysUtils;

type
  TMyCallBack = procedure (const Foo : string) of object;
  TMyClass    = class
    procedure DoSomething(const Foo: String);
  end;

  TMyAnotherClass  = class
  private
    FDoSomething: TMyCallBack;
  published
    property DoSomething : TMyCallBack read FDoSomething Write FDoSomething;
  end;

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.DoSomething(const Foo: String);
begin
  Writeln('Hello');
end;

Var
  MyClass : TMyClass;
  t       : TRttiInstanceType;
  v       : TValue;
  p       : TRttiProperty;
  Bar     : TMyCallBack;
begin
  try
    MyClass:=TMyClass.Create;
    try
      t:=TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TMyAnotherClass).AsInstance;
      v:=t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[]);
      p:=t.GetProperty('DoSomething');
      Bar:=MyClass.DoSomething;
      if p<>nil then
       p.SetValue(v.AsObject, @Bar); //here the exception is raised
    finally
     MyClass.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

How i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I traced into the error line, I ended up on the implicit TClass->TValue conversion routine.  It looks like @Bar is a pointer, and the compiler is implicitly converting that to a TClass, and from there everything gets messed up.  That's not what you want.

What you need is an actual TValue whose type and value match Bar.  Try this:

```
Var
  MyClass : TMyClass;
  t       : TRttiInstanceType;
  v       : TValue;
  p       : TRttiProperty;
  Bar     : TMyCallBack;
  vBar    : TValue;
begin
  try
    MyClass:=TMyClass.Create;
    try
      t:=TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TMyAnotherClass).AsInstance;
      v:=t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[]);
      p:=t.GetProperty('DoSomething');
      Bar:=MyClass.DoSomething;
      vBar := TValue.From<TMyCallback>(bar);
      if p<>nil then
       p.SetValue(v.AsObject, vBar); //here the exception is raised
    finally
     MyClass.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: @Salvador: You're welcome. And you might want to report this as an error to QC: A pointer to a method reference should not be eligible for an implicit conversion to TClass by the compiler!